# How does flutter framework call createSate() method & generally how does framework calls your code?

Tags: flutter, dart, frameworks

```
class Myclass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyclassState();
}
```

I was wondering how flutter framework calls the `createState()` method,since in there documentation have stated that "The framework can call this method multiple times over the lifetime of a `StatefulWidget`".

It is not clear to me how the method gets calls since I cannot find the call statement that actually invokes the `createSate()` method.

Additionally I have read that one of the principles of frameworks is inversion of control(framework calling your code). I am struggling trying to wrap my head around that concept but I cannot deeply understand how it does that. A comprehensive explanation can be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.